# Showing that the McCarthy Function is a well-defined function from the set of positive integers to the set of positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

For those of you who aren't familiar, the McCarthy Function states that $M(n) = n − 10$ if $n > 100$ and $M(M(n + 11))$ if $n \leq 100$ (a recursive function).

I'm trying to prove that this function is a well-defined function from the set of positive integers to the set of positive integers, and I'm starting off by proving that $M(n) = 91$ for all positive integers $n$ with $n \leq 101$.  Here's how I approached the proof:

For $90 \leq n < 101$,

$$\begin{array}{rl} M(n) &= M(M(n + 11))\\
&= M(n + 11 - 10), \, \text{where}\, n + 11 \geq 101\,\, \text{since}\, \, n \geq 90 \\
&= M(n + 1)\end{array}$$

So $M(n) = 91$ for $90 ≤ n < 101$.

We can use this as a base case for induction on blocks of $11$ numbers, like so:

Assume that $M(n) = 91$ for $a ≤ n < a + 11$.

Then, for any $n$ such that $a - 11 ≤ n < a$,

$$\begin{array}{rl} M(n) &= M(M(n + 11))\\
&= M(91), \text{ by hypothesis, since } a ≤ n + 11 < a + 11 \\
&= 91, \text{ by the base case}.
\end{array}$$

Now by induction $M(n) = 91$ for any $n$ in such a block. There are no holes between the blocks, so $M(n) = 91$ for $n < 101$. We can also add $n = 101$ as a special case.

Do you think this is sufficient for the proof or would there be any other steps you'd recommend I take?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is word for word the argument given in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthy_91_function) on the function; unfortunately there’s a small gap in it.

If correctly shows that $M(n)=M(n+1)$ if $90\le n<101$, but it does not justify the conclusion that $M(n)=91$ for $90\le n<101$. However, from what has been shown it follows, either by a finite induction or by writing it out longhand, that

$$M(90)=M(91)=\ldots=M(100)=M(101)=101-10=91\;,$$

and you get the result that you wanted.

The rest of the Wikipedia argument is correct.

Comment: I know!  I was just trying to make sure that the proof was correct in that it explains what I'm trying to find.  I realize that this is a correct proof, but does it correctly show that the function is well defined from set of positive integers to set of positive integers?  Thanks!

Comment: @jtm22: As I said, it’s not quite correct, because of the gap that I noted and filled. Once that gap is filled, it’s a correct proof that $M$ is a well-defined function from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$; there’s no need to limit the domain to the **positive** integers.

Comment: Might I ask why you don't need to limit it to positive integers?  Is it because it'd be the same thing?

Comment: The induction step (showing that if $M(n)=91$ for $a\le n<a+11$, then $M(n)=91$ for $a-11\le n<a$) works no matter what $a$ is, so the induction actually proves that $M(n)=91$ for all integers $n\le 101$, positive, negative, or zero.